# Проверка удерживания клавиши

Tags: javascript

Добрый день.

Реализовал проверку удерживания клавиши по методу:

**http://jsfiddle.net/krbm09op/**

Но дело в том, что если зажать клавишу и, не отпуская ее, перейти на другую вкладку, и отпустить уже там, вернувшись на нашу вкладку, мы увидим, что данная клавиша считается удерживаемой.

Причину проблемы я понимаю, а вот как ее решить - нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дополнительно отслеживать фокус вкладки

Comment: Добавил onblur и oncontextmenu.
Правда, отследить уже такое, как открытие настроек браузера (например, Google Chrome), думаю, уже невозможно.